# Почему не работает flex-wrap при просмотре кода страницы?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
@font-face {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  src: url(../fonts/montserrat.ttf);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  color: #e6eaed;
  background-color: #e6eaed;
  height: 2px;
}

.social-footer:first-child {
  margin-left: -24px;
}

button {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 48.38px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #fa5c65;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: flex;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 31px;
  padding-right: 31px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 1370px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h1 {
  color: #314a5b;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 53px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-title {
  margin-top: 300px;
}

h1:after {
  content: ".";
  color: #fa5c65;
}

h3 {
  color: #314a5b;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 40.35px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.content {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 950px;
}

.header {
  background-image: url(../img/TitlePhoto.png);
  max-width: 1370px;
  height: 1057px;
}

.header>.content {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logo {
  width: 141px;
  height: 74px;
  background-color: #fa5c65;
  border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo a {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 86px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo a:after {
  content: ".";
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #314a5b;
}

.menu ul {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 36px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 36px;
}

.menu ul .social {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.menu ul .social a i {
  color: #fa5c65;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu ul .social a i:hover {
  color: #263742;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #263742;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 85px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 {
  color: #465065;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2:after {
  content: ".";
  color: #f0454c;
}

h4 {
  color: #9aa0ab;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.more {
  color: #fa5c65;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.article-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

i {
  margin-left: 24px;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 255px;
}

.portfolio {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 100px;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.portfolio img {
  max-width: 398px;
}

.portfolio_text {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.our-team {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.our-team h4 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.portfolio_note {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.portfolio_article {
  margin-top: 40px;
  max-width: 367px;
}

.all-workers {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.worker {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.about {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.name {
  display: block;
  color: #314a5b;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h5 {
  color: #f0454c;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex-basis: 260px;
}

.our-team>.more {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-top: 66px;
}

.social-footer a i {
  color: #b9c0c6;
}

.social-footer a i:hover {
  color: #618B85;
}

.autor {
  color: #b9c0c6;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .content {
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  .portfolio_text {
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .portfolio_article {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
  .article-wrap {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .all-workers {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .worker {
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .content {
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
    .portfolio_text {
      margin-left: 60px;
      margin-bottom: 60px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .portfolio_article {
      max-width: 500px;
    }
    .article-wrap {
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .worker {
      justify-content: center;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 670px) {
      ul.social {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .all-workers {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
      }
      .header>.content {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .main-title {
        font-size: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 100px;
      }
      button {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
      h3 {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .portfolio img {
        max-width: 300px;
      }
      .article-wrap {
        justify-content: center;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
      h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }
      .menu ul {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      button {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
      h3 {
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Freelancer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <header class="header">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="logo"><a href="#">Freelancer</a></div>
        <nav class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#part1">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#part2">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#part3">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#part4">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="social"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div>
          <h1 class="main-title">intelligence </br>is nothing without</br> ambition</h1>
          <h3>We’re small but impressive creative agency.</h3>
          <button>read more</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="article-wrap">
        <article>
          <h2>Peace <br>of Mind</h2>
          <h4>You’re safe with us. The privacy and security of your financial information is our top priority.</h4>
          <a href="#" class="more">read more <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Free<br> Actually free</h2>
          <h4>No more pricing grids. No more fine print. Sending and receiving cash is free without gimmicks.</h4>
          <a href="#" class="more">read more <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Simple<br> payments</h2>
          <h4>The same debit card you use to buy coffee lets deposit money straight to your bank account.</h4>
          <a href="#" class="more">read more <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio" id="part2">
        <img src="img/macbook.png" alt="">
        <div class="portfolio_text">
          <h1>porfolio</h1>
          <h3 class="portfolio_note">
            <p>We are small, but strong team</h3>
          <h4 class="portfolio_article">No more pricing grids. No more fine print. Sending and receiving cash is free without gimmicks.
            </p><br> The same debit card you use to buy coffee lets deposit money straight to your bank account.</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="our-team" id="part3">
        <h1>our team</h1>
        <h4>They are big but still friendly.</h4>
        <div class="all-workers">
          <div class="worker">
            <img src="img/oneWorker.png" alt="">
            <div class="about">
              <span class="name">Joey</span>
              <h5>Web developer</h5>
              <h4>Coffee lover. Always <br>on bike. iPhone fan.</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="worker">
            <img src="img/TwoWorker.png" alt="">
            <div class="about">
              <span class="name">Matt</span>
              <h5>Web designer</h5>
              <h4>MTB Biker. Photoshop <br>Master. Loving Father.</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="worker">
            <img src="img/FreWorker.png" alt="">
            <div class="about">
              <span class="name">Mike</span>
              <h5>Copywriter</h5>
              <h4>Drummer. Soup lover. <br> Beer Drinker. Cyclist.</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="more">read more <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>

      <footer class="footer" id="part4">
        <hr>
        <div class="social-footer">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <span class="autor">© Freelancer - Designed by Wojtek Kwiatkowski</span>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Сверстал адаптивный макет, использовал flex. Смотрел адаптивность сужая окно браузера, так всё работало, но когда открыл код страницы, удивился. Flex-wrap не работал, а работали только медиа запросы. Как сделать так чтобы flex-wrap работал так как пишут в справочниках? То есть при сужении окна браузера выводил flex-элементы на новую строку.
При просмотре кода:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При сжатие браузера, меню встало как надо:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без кода не понять..

Comment: Здравствуйте, при просмотре кода на этом сайте почему-то он адаптивный, но когда я смотрю код через свой браузер, то сайт не адаптируется.

Comment: ctrl+shift+r нажимаете?

Answer (score 2):

Вставьте в html между head такую строчку

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Какую такую?......